# Hibernate Hql orderby problems

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by

I am using Hibernate, and I have a problem with HQL. I have users who have a latitude and longitude, and I need to compare distances between the user logged and the other users in a query and order it. What I need to do is `(userloged.latitude - user.latitude)^2 + (userloged.longitude - user.longitude)^2` in the query. I have the user logged, and I need to get the < 20 nearest to him. Thanks.

```
public List<Usuarios> getAllUsuarios(String correito, String desea) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.session = sf.openSession();
    Query query;
    if(desea.equals("Ambos"))
        query = session.createQuery("FROM Usuarios WHERE correo != '" + correito + "' ORDER BY ");
    else
    {
        if(desea.equals("Hombres"))
            desea = "Hombre";
        else if(desea.equals("Mujeres"))
            desea = "Mujer";
        query = session.createQuery("FROM Usuarios WHERE correo != '" + correito + "' AND genero = '" + desea + "'");
    }
    query.setMaxResults(MAX);
    List<Usuarios> usuarios = (List<Usuarios>) query.list();

    session.close();

    return usuarios;
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't see any attempt in the code at doing what you want. Also, don't use string concatenation to pass parameters. Use named parameters.